# If there is a list of "cultures" to download somewhere

Tags: database

I am wondering if there is a list similar to the ISO country codes but for *cultures*. Specifically like this:

```
chinese
japanese
american
russian
etc.
```

Whereas the country codes list it like this:

```
China
Japan
...etc.
```

Comment: There is ISO 639 but it seems used for localization settings (e.g. Catalan speakers in Spain) rather than an anthropologist’s definition of a “culture”. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22624395/2327328

Comment: Also, “culture” is a loaded term. It could mean language, ethnicity, religion, etc. Cultures can be macro or micro and are certainly multi-dimensional. Not so easy to find a dataset without a precise definition of “culture”. In your example, all 4 “cultures” would be considered somewhere controversial.

Comment: https://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/geonode:GREG_0vV isn't exactly what you're looking for but may be helpful.